# UITableView Cells Separated and with Rounded Corners

Tags: xcode, uitableview, rounded-corners

The title may seem odd but I am trying to make a to-do list app where the tasks are in a UITableView that looks like Wunderlist's where it doesn't touch the edges and has rounded corners with spacing between each task. I am new to Xcode and cannot find any answers online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create view inside a tableview cell and set its bottom constraint to the space you want to give and on that view apply corner radius using

`view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
view.layer.masksToBounds = true;`